# elasticsearch query_string keyword search with or operator not working

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string

I have created a simple reproducer for this issue as following :

```
PUT trial
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [ "lowercase" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "status": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
PUT trial/_doc/2
{
  "status": "not_installed"
}

PUT trial/_doc/1
{
  "status": "installed"
}
POST trial/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "not_installed installed",
            "default_operator": "or"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If I execute these commands from top to bottom one by one, I expect doc 1,2 as results. But it's not getting fetched. What is wrong with my understanding ? Can someone help ?
Working with ES version 7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below search query (taking same index mapping and data)

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "not_installed OR installed"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above query gives the expected result. To know more about `query_string` refer to this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

**UPDATE 1:**

> Elasticsearch relies on the analyzer to split everything that is
> in-between query operators into terms. And the analyzer on `keyword` fields is a `keyword` analyzer.

> So there has to be a way to configure keyword fields so that text
> would be split on whitespace at query time. Therefore,
> `split_queries_on_whitespace` parameter is added to the field that
> sets a whitespace analyzer as a search analyzer when set to true.
> By adding this parameter and setting it to true full-text queries (`match`, `multi_match`, `query_string`,..) that target the field will split the input on whitespace to build the query terms.

Refer to these GitHub issues to know more about this:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/29148
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/30131
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/30393
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/30691

**In your case you need to add `split_queries_on_whitespace` parameter to the keyword field to split the input on whitespace when building a query for the field `status`. To know more about this refer to this official documentation on [Keyword datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/keyword.html).**

**Index Mapping:**

Modified mapping will look like this :

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [ "lowercase" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "status": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "split_queries_on_whitespace": true   --> note this
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query :**

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "installed not_installed",
            "default_operator":"OR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "status": "not_installed"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "status": "installed"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: yes I am aware that this works. My question was that having "default_operator": "or" should be same as specifying OR in the query but that doesn't work.

Comment: @voidMainReturn please go through my updated answer

Comment: @voidMainReturn glad I could be of your help :) And thank u for accepting and upvoting the answer :)